# Error in applying different if statements to each element of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, if-statement

Good morning, I have a simple question about applying a different if statement to every element of a numpy array.
I have written a function that take as input a numpy array made of 12 elements, checks if the element is 0 or 1 and, if it's 1, acts on another array. The function is the following:

```
def symmetry_test(determinant):
    print(determinant)
    ag=np.array([1,1,1,1])
    bg=np.array([1,-1,-1,1])
    au=np.array([1,1,-1,-1])
    bu=np.array([1,-1,1,-1])
    representations=np.zeros((4,12))
    print(determinant[0])
    if int(determinant[0])==1:
       representations[:,0]=au
   
    print(determinant[1])
    if int(determinant[1])==1:
       representations[:,1]=au
   
    print(determinant[2])
    if determinant[2]==1:
       representations[:,2]=ag

    print(determinant[3])
    if determinant[3]==1:
       representations[:,3]=ag
  
    if determinant[4]==1:
       representations[:,4]=bg

    if determinant[5]==1:
       representations[:,5]=bg
 
    if determinant[6]==1:
       representations[:,6]=ag
   
    if determinant[7]==1:
       representations[:,7]=ag
 
    if determinant[8]==1:
       representations[:,1]=bu

    if determinant[9]==1:
       representations[:,9]=bu
 
    if determinant[10]==1:
       representations[:,10]=au
  
    if determinant[11]==1:
       representations[:,11]=au

    idx = np.argwhere(np.all(representations[..., :] == 0, axis=0))
    representations = np.delete(representations, idx, axis=1)
    return representations
```

The function takes `determinant` as input, which is a numpy array, generates an array called `representations` and fills it. I put `print(determinant[0])`and `int(determinant[0])` in the definition to check if the function reads the array properly.
The problem is the following: if I give as input an array defined as `test=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0])` the function works fine and returns and array like

```
 1  1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1 -1 -1
-1 -1  1  1  1  1
-1 -1  1  1 -1 -1
```

which is exactly what I want.
Now, if I give to the function the array `test=np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])` and use it as `a=symmetry_test(test)`,the output is

```
 1  1  1  1  1
 1 -1  1  1 -1
-1  1  1  1  1
-1 -1  1  1 -1
```

(yes, it only has 5 columns)
instead of

```
 1  1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1 -1 -1
-1 -1  1  1 -1 -1
-1 -1  1  1  1  1
```

Honestly I have no idea of the reason why it doesn't work and what puzzles me the most is the fact that for one array it works and for another it fails completely.
I tried to punt the else condition

```
else:
    representations[:,0]=np.zeros(4)
```

after each if statement without success; I also tried to put  `determinant=np.asarray(determinant)` at the beginning of the function but, also in this case, it didn't solve the problem.
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the easy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in your code.

```
if determinant[8] == 1:
    representations[:, 1] = bu
```

Should be

```
if determinant[8] == 1:
    representations[:, 8] = bu
```

And if you want a more concise way of implementing that function, consider this -

```
def symmetry_test(determinant):
    
    ag = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
    bg = np.array([1, -1, -1, 1])
    au = np.array([1, 1, -1, -1])
    bu = np.array([1, -1, 1, -1])

    representations = np.array([au, au, ag, ag, bg, bg, ag, ag, bu, bu, au, au])

    determinant = np.array(determinant, dtype=np.bool)

    return representations[determinant]
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I examined the code several times and I don't know how I missed it but the important thing is that now it works, thanks again.

Comment: @capitn96 - You don't really need all that if conditions to do this by the way, I have added a concise way of doing this. Also, if this solves your issue, please mark the answer as right and consider closing the question.